# How to add span class between primary and secondary link

Tags: jquery

I am new to this so need some help.
What I want to do is...
I want to give span to ul of primary link i.e secondary link using jQuery. I hope this is clear.
Thanx in advanced.

Comment: How do you mean primary/secondary link? Some code could help.

Comment: Hi,
Let me take this webpage for example. The links "Questions", "Tags"...son is my primary link and on my website this links have sublink which the secondary link. Unfortunately I dont have the code for the website. My Question is basically the assignment given to me. PLease help. Also this is on Drupal platform. I hope now its a bit more precise.
Thanx for your time.

Comment: That was totally confusing. Do you have an Unordered List with Links and you want to add a <p> tag to the links?

Comment: yes...The first link(Primary link) has sublink(secondary link) which are unordered links  however I dont want to add <p> but a <span> so that we could change the style of the menu. Please Help!!!

Comment: Some code is worth a thousand words.

Comment: Dude, edit your post and add the code there.... not here in comments.... can't read it.

Comment: Its not letting me edit the post for some reason...

<li id="menu-116" class="menu-path-node-1 primary-acitve">
<a class="active" title="Home" href="/home">home</a>
</li>
<li id="menu-117" class="menuparent menu-path-node-2">
<a title="Services">services</a>
<ul>
<li id="menu-396" class="menu-path-node-123 empty">
<a title="empty link" href="/empty-link">empty link</a>
</li>
**This is my code for the links**(Its just for one of the links to get an understanding)

Answer (score 0):

Let me draw you up an image...... is this something you are thinking of?

```
<ul>
 <li> My primary link 1</li>
   <ul>
     <li> My secondary link 1 </li>
     <li> My secondary link 2 </li>
     <li> My secondary link 3 </li>
   </ul>
 <li> My primary link 2</li>
   <ul>
     <li> My secondary link 1 </li>
     <li> My secondary link 2 </li>
     <li> My secondary link 3 </li>
   </ul>
</ul>
```

If this is what you want, why not just output it using UL's and style the lists with css?